# universal Coxeter group and reduced expression

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that

Coxeter group is universal type iff each element has a unique reduced expression.

I think this question is elementary but I can't solve...

Comment: How have you defined universal type? All edges being labelled with $\infty$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  Yes. you are right!

Answer (score 0):

So given that a Coxeter group of universal type has been clarified to be one of the form $\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\mid x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2\rangle$, we need to show two things:

1) If a group has this form, then any element has a unique reduced expression.

2) If each element in a Coxeter group has a unique reduced expression, then for any two distinct generators $x_i$ and $x_j$ the element $x_ix_j$ has infinite order.

Proof of 1) It is a general result for Coxeter groups that given two reduced expressions for an element, one can be obtained from the other by applying braid relations corresponding to those of the Coxeter group. Since there are no braid relations in the given Coxeter group, there can be only one reduced expression for each element.

Proof of 2) If an element $x_ix_j$ has finite order $m$ then this gives a relation of the form $x_ix_jx_j\cdots x_k = x_jx_ix_j\cdots x_l$ ($m$ terms on each side, where $k = i$ if $m$ is odd and $k=j$ otherwise while $l$ is $i$ if $m$ is even and $j$ otherwise). This produces two distinct reduced expressions for the element $x_ix_jx_i\cdots x_k$.

As an aside: The set of elements which have a unique reduced expression forms what is called a $2$-sided cell in the Coxeter group. At least for finite Coxeter groups, this cell is a lot easier to understand than the rest.